# WPF Dispatcher.InvokeAsync() strange behavior with async delegate

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, dispatcher

If you have an async method, like the one below:

```
    private async Task DoAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"(1.1)");
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Console.WriteLine(@"(1.2)");
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(@"(1.3)");
    }
```

and you call it asynchronously with Dispatcher:

```
        Console.WriteLine(@"(1)");
        await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(DoAsync);
        Console.WriteLine(@"(2)");
```

The output you'll get will be:
(1)
(1.1)
(1.2)
(2)
(1.3)

If you use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() and you'll wait for Completed event, the effect will be the same (which is expected):

```
        Console.WriteLine(@"(1)");
        var dispatcherOp = Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Func<Task>(DoAsync));
        dispatcherOp.Completed += (s, args) =>
        {               
        Console.WriteLine(@"(2)");
        };
```

What we see here is that the await in DoAsync() method makes Dispatcher believe the operation ended.

My question: is it a bug or a feature? Do you know any document that describes this behavior? I couldn't find anything.

*I'm not asking for a workaround.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a bug in your code, the object returned from `Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(DoAsync);` is a `Task<Task>`, you only await the outer task, not waiting for the inner task to complete. These situations is what [`.Unwrap()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917(v=vs.110).aspx) is for.

```
    Console.WriteLine(@"(1)");
    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(DoAsync).Unwrap();
    Console.WriteLine(@"(2)");
```

The output you will get will be: (1) (1.1) (1.2) (1.3) (2)

What Unwrap is doing is effectively turning your code in to

```
    Console.WriteLine(@"(1)");
    await (await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(DoAsync));
    Console.WriteLine(@"(2)");
```

But with a nicer looking format.

For documentation see "[How to: Unwrap a nested task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-unwrap-a-nested-task)"

Comment: Thanks for the super-useful answer! :)

Comment: I can write `InvokeAsync(DoAsync).Task.Unwrap()` but not `InvokeAsync(DoAsync).Unwrap()`. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @oleh: Dispatcher.InvokeAsync returns a DispatcherOperation, not a Task, however, it is awaitable, therefore the await keyword works. To get the Task and do the unwrap: Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(DoAsync).Task.Unwrap()

Comment: await await is faster than Unwrap(), [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34832315/4108016)