# C# - Dispatcher.InvokeAsync ContinueWith not awaited

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

Assuming `ChartViewModels` is an `ObservableCollection<T>`, the following code works as expected:

```
await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
{
    ChartViewModels.Clear();
    ChartViewModels.AddRange(initializedCharts);
}, DispatcherPriority.DataBind, mCancellationToken.Token);

await UpdateChartsWithValuesAsync(chartsToInitialize, ChartViewModels).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Instead, if I wrap the the `UpdateChartsWithValuesAsync` method call in the `ContinueWith` delegate, the method is not awaited anymore. I already tried to change the `ConfigureAwait(false)` to `true` but nothing seems to change. Below the edited code:

```
await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
{
    ChartViewModels.Clear();
    ChartViewModels.AddRange(initializedCharts);
}, DispatcherPriority.DataBind, mCancellationToken.Token).Task
.ContinueWith(async t => await UpdateChartsWithValuesAsync(chartsToInitialize, ChartViewModels).ConfigureAwait(false), mCancellationToken.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Current).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The code into the `Dispatcher` is always executed before the `ContinueWith` delegate, but it doesn't await `UpdateChartsWithValuesAsync` to complete anymore, raising nasty bugs.

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Thanks

WPF, .NET Framework 4.7 project

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think UpdateChartsWithValuesAsync is actually awaited, but on another thread. Try not to mix async/await with tools that were mostly useful before async/await existed (like ContinueWith... I have no idea why you'd want to use it here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, `.ContinueWith()` does not do `await` in its implementation, instead runs the passed in delegate as it is and returns a Task of Task (`Task<Task>>`). This outer task, because not awaiting on the passed in delegate, completes immediately.

What I suggest, don't use `.ContinueWith()` in this case, simply stick to await. If you really keen to keep the current code, you can do `.ContinueWith().Unwrap()`, what will does the trick.

Also here is an another related question in the topic: [Use an async callback with Task.ContinueWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697167/use-an-async-callback-with-task-continuewith)

If you wanna learn more in depth, the source code of `ContinueWith`: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs,4532

Comment: Good answer. An alternative to `Unwrap` is awaiting twice: [`await await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816628/await-await-vs-unwrap.)

Answer (score 1):

`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` returns a `DispatcherOperation`. This is an awaitable type, as it implements a method called `GetAwaiter()` that returns a type that implements `INotifyCompletion`.

When you use `await` on the result of `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` directly, the completion of `DispatcherOperation` is awaited before the call to `UpdateChartsWithValuesAsync`.

In your second example, you do not await this directly; you are awaiting the result of the chained expression:

```
Dispatcher
    .InvokeAsync()   // returns DispatcherOperation
    .Task            // returns Task
    .ContinueWith(); // returns another Task
```

So only the final object (`Task`) is awaited, meaning the function you pass to `ContinueWith` may be executed, before `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` has completed.

If you are using async / await, it would be prudent to **only** use the keywords in an async method, as mixing with the callback based operations leads to confusing code such as this.

Answer (score 1):

As other answer mentioned, you shouldn't put `async t => await UpdateChartsWithValuesAsync` in your `ContinueWith` callback as it would result in awaiting the `Task<Task> ContinueWith(...)` method, which would eventually finish immediately.

If you really want to wait for ContinueWith to finish in most outer `await` you should `Unwrap()` your `Task<Task>` and await, or use synchronous API inside, but remember about the correct management of the synchronization context.

```
await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
{
    ChartViewModels.Clear();
    ChartViewModels.AddRange(initializedCharts);
}, DispatcherPriority.DataBind, mCancellationToken.Token).Task
.ContinueWith(t => UpdateChartsWithValuesAsync(), mCancellationToken.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Current)
.Unwrap()
.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Note that `await` is translated into code block involving `ContinueWith` which features `ConfigureAwait` options and more, so you better use `async await` constructions like you tried in your first example.