# How to create a new generic Task using an async lamda as argument

Tags: c#, task

I need to create a new generic task that takes an async lambda but does not start right away. That's why I can't use `Task.Run` and I would like to instantiate a new task. I couldn’t do this because C# gives me the error below:

> Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type `Func<int>`.
> An async lambda expression may return `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>`, none of
> which are convertible to `Func<int>`

My code is

```
Task<int> task = new Task(async () => {
    var number = await getNextNumber();
    return await algorithm(number);
});
```

Comment: Do you need to return a value? For an asynchronous function like this, it seems that you can't have return values.

Comment: @Nigel Do I understand correctly that you need an async function with deferred execution?

Comment: Is the problem solved? Have you seen Stephen Cleary's answer?

Answer (score 3):

> I need to create a new generic task that takes an async lambda but does not start right away. That's why I can't use Task.Run and I would like to instantiate a new task.

You should [never, ever use the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html), as I explain on my blog.

In the synchronous world, if you want an object that can be invoked later to execute some code, you use a delegate, e.g., `Action` or `Func<T>`.

In the asynchronous world, if you want an object that can be invoked later to execute some code, you use a delegate. [The delegate types for asynchronous lambdas are different than the synchronous ones](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html), as I explain on my blog; so instead of `Action` you'd use `Func<Task>`, and instead of `Func<T>` you'd use `Func<Task<T>>`.

```
Func<Task<int>> func = async () => {
    var number = await getNextNumber();
    return await algorithm(number);
};

...

int result = await func();
```

Comment: I read your blog, your explanation was amazing and you do deserve kudos for that.

Answer (score 2):

The generic task class `Task<T>` does not have a constructor that takes `Func<Task<T>>` as an argument and for that reason you cannot decorate your lambda with the async keyword. However, the non-generic task class `Task` does allow for passing in asynchronous lamdas.

A workaround would be to create a wrapper around the `Task<T>` class to make this possible in such a way that you could also await the inner task.

```
public class SuperTask<T>
{
    private Task<T> task;
    private Func<Task<T>> function;
    public SuperTask(Func<Task<T>> function)
    {
        this.function = function;
    }
    public SuperTask<T> Start()
    {
        task = function();
        return this;
    }
    public Task<T> AsTask() {
        return task;
    }
}

// And you can test it like so
SuperTask<int> testCase = new SuperTask<int>(async ()=> {
   await Task.Delay(1000); 
   return 0;
});
int number = await testCase.Start().AsTask();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

```
Task<int> task = new Task<int>(() =>
    getNextNumber()
        .ContinueWith(t => algorithm(t.Result))
        .Unwrap()
        .Result
);
```

Good old `ContinueWith` plus `Unwrap`.

It looks ugly, but it should work.

Comment: Please have a look at the accepted answer of this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816628/await-await-vs-unwrap/34832315.